# Export sklearn and/or xgboost model object for use in excel or vba?

Tags: python, excel, scikit-learn, export, xgboost

I've currently trained & tested several supervised models using sklearn and xgboost (using the same data). The xgboost model performs slightly better than sklearn's LassoCV.

I'm trying to find a way to export the model object so that it can be interacted with by non-technical folks in either Excel and/or VBA. Specifically, non-technical folk need to be able to enter all feature values for a new observation, and have the exported sklearn or xgboost model output a new prediction.

I know I can save sklearn and xgboost objects down as .pkl. Is there an interface or API that can take input from excel, pass it to the .pkl model file, and return the correct scalar prediction? There are about 40-50 features that will need to be inputted and passed to the exported model. After exporting the model from python, it will not need to retrained, only used for prediction.

Comment: d u plan to run a python-made model on a no-python-installed pc?

Comment: No - I need to assume that Python will not be installed on the non-tech folks' PCs.

Comment: imho, if you can re-create the model [(python file) as exe](https://pythonexamples.org/python-py-to-exe/). The model should be able to run in a no-python-installed environment. Automation should be possible to work  out once that is done.

Comment: You can use [m2cgen](https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen) to transform your model to VBA and then use it in excel with a macro.